# Не отображается карта с API v2

Tags: google-maps, android, google-maps-api, java

Получила ключ по SHA1,добавила все необходимые разрешения в Manifest.xml, библиотеки - в проект, использую следующий код:

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap myMap;
Location myLocation;
 private UiSettings mUiSettings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment 
     = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (myMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        myMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (myMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {

    myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
      //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
      //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    mUiSettings = myMap.getUiSettings();

    mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mUiSettings.setCompassEnabled(true);
}
```

Вместо карты пустой экран с элементами управления зумом и отображения текущего местоположения.
Кто разобрался с новой версией, напишите, пожалуйста, пошагово что именно необходимо добавлять в код, если есть возможность, выложите полностью код .xml и .java, либо подскажите в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: Глупый вопрос, а вы debug-ключ получили или release ?

Comment: @s01nyshko, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

У вас либо неверный ключ API, либо проверьте в консоли разработчика стоит ли флажок около Google Map Android v2 в On.

А вообще, сейчас сам сталкиваюсь со сложностями апи 2 версии. Такие же проблемы, только приложение падает с непонятными ошибками.

**UPD**
Сложности поборол - все хорошо:) главное взять library-проект из SDK/extras/.../play_services(пути примерные) и подключить к своему проекту.

Comment: DroidAlex, флажок стоит. А как понять, что ключ неверный? Я уже и просто по SHA1 получала, и по SHA1;название пакета приложения. 
А у Вас оно ни на эмуляторе ни на телефоне не запускается?

Comment: У меня карта работает, но только когда использую сам фрагмент карты как вкладку, но не работает, когда использую его в макете и подгружаю. Ну если ключ в консоле создался и отображается(Android-ключ), то просто скопируйте его в манифест в тег application добавив <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="ваш_ключ_тут" />

Comment: Подробный пошаговый ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696620/google-maps-android-api-v2-authorization-failure

Comment: В манифесте ключ добавлен именно таким способом. А вот с фрагментом карты не очень понятно, как вкладку чего использовать надо, чтоб она работала? Я уже и просто <fragment добавляла в xml и внутри RelativeLayuot делала. А в примере по ссылке вообще <FrameLayout лежит и даже без class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"...

Comment: Проблема может быть также в том, что на устройстве старые карты, которые нужно обновить. Также нужно проверить наличие интернета. И добавьте логи - если есть

Answer (score 1):

А вы на чем пробуете отлаживать? Если на эмуляторе то с ним все плохо, а на устройстве может работать! Создавая УСТРОЙСТВО ЭМУЛЯТОРА выберите в target не Android версию, а Google APIs

Comment: Ariox, а если происходит бесконечная загрузка при параметре Google API? Может сталкивались уже с такой проблемой.